# Is hydroperoxyl radical(HO2) toxic to the human body, or even flammable?

Tags: radicals

[image: Hydroperoxyl radical]

I understand that radicals are damaging to cells, due to their high chemical reactivity. Though I do not know whether they are flammable in any level.

Comment: Flammability is a property of compounds. A radical can't be flammable, much like it can't be happy or thoughtful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very reactive.  It is an oxidizer rather than a flammable substance.

You can't collect a significant amount in one place because it will react with itself:

$\ce{HO2 + HO2 -> H2O2 + O2 }$